# Finding all linear transformations.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I am currently working with Andrew McInerney book "First Steos in Differential Geometry: Riemannian, Contact, Symplectic". There is a problem in chapter 2 (Linear Algebra Essentials) where I could solve the (a) part of the question but I struggled with the (b). Therefore I hope someone can give a hint or solution to the (b). The problem is stated as follows:

Let $\alpha \in (\mathbb{R}^3)^*$ be given by $\alpha(x,y,z) = 4y+z$.

- (a) Find the $\ker \alpha$.
- (b) Find all linear tranformations $\psi : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ with the property that $\psi^*\alpha=\alpha$.

Comment: Could you tell us what you've tried so far? That helps providing you with a better answer.

Comment: Yes, in particular how you express $\psi^*\alpha.$

Comment: *If* you like to solve this matricially, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258326) can help.

Comment: I tried with $(\psi^* \alpha)(v) = \alpha(\psi(v))$, if $\alpha(x,y,z)= 4y+z$, then I concluded that $(\psi^* \alpha)(v) = \alpha(\psi(v))= 4\psi_{2}(v) + \psi_{3}(v)$. Assuming the standard dual basis then $4\psi_{2}(0,1,0) + \psi_{3}(0,1,0)= 4$ and $4\psi_{2}(0,0,1) + \psi_{3}(0,0,1)= 1$. And I dont know where the next step is or if the begging of my solutions is wrongly reasoned.

Comment: The space of linear transformations $\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ is $9$-dimensional, and you have only three equations to determine $\psi$. So you expect a (linear) $6$-dimensional space of such linear transformations.

Comment: In what sense do you want to find the linear transformations in (b)? Parametrize that set? Find a basis for $\{\psi - 1\}$?